# preventDefault, Scroll on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scrolltop

I have this script in jQuery, it scrolls to wanted section but with spacing to the top. It works fine on all tested browsers ... except firefox.

```
$('nav > *').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var navClicked = $(this).index();
    var elem = $(this).attr("href");
    $('body').scrollTop($(elem).offset().top - 48);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5L3xyuuv/1/

Comment: add your html codes too or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @frnt https://jsfiddle.net/5L3xyuuv/1/

Comment: what kind of a test page is that? it's almost empty and doesn't reproduce the problem

Comment: why did you do all this javascript anyway if it simply "jumps" to the `id` location on the page like a regular hash link does?

Comment: because your 'jump' ignores the header height if theres one

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, add `HTML` and `BODY` to `scrollTop()` method, this works perfectly on all browser.

```js
$('nav > *').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var navClicked = $(this).index();
    var elem = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html,body').scrollTop($(elem).offset().top - 48);
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}

#about{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#111;
}

#benefits{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#ccc;
}

#team{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#f22;
}

#path{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#f2f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#about">about</a>
  <a href="#benefits">benefits</a>
  <a href="#team">team</a>
  <a href="#path">path</a>
</nav>

<div id="about"></div>
<div id="benefits"></div>
<div id="team"></div>
<div id="path"></div>
```

Comment: your snippet works fine, but if ill copy it to my snippet, it stops working

Comment: Could it be, that other jquery scripts cause this, but only on firefox?

Comment: Then you need to go through your codes, as per your query this works perfectly fine on all browser.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).scrollTop(...);
solves the problem.